# Java client to set SAS, Policy and CORS on Azure

Tags: java, azure, cors

I'm trying to set CORS properties on Azure using Java client. After executing code, I run HTML5 code to upload a file and facing following errors in chrome javascript console:

> max block size = 47276
>
> total blocks = 1
>
> https:myacc.blob.core.windows.net/mycon/ch1.jpg?sr=c&sv=2015-04-05&sig=djbVxIBlyVy18bV0SkqNSLql1n9efAVcYnGy3VsGKis%3D&si=champ
>
> current file pointer = 0 bytes read = 47276
>
> block id = block-000000
>
> https:myacc.blob.core.windows.net/mycon/ch1.jpg?sr=c&sv=2015-0…kqNSLql1n9efAVcYnGy3VsGKis%3D&si=champ&comp=block&blockid=YmxvY2stMDAwMDAw
>
> **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (CORS not enabled or no matching rule found for this request.)**
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https:myacc.blob.core.windows.net/mycon/ch1.jpg?sr=c&sv=2015-0…kqNSLql1n9efAVcYnGy3VsGKis%3D&si=heath&comp=block&blockid=YmxvY2stMDAwMDAw.
>
> **Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   response had HTTP status code 403.**

**What I'm wondering is why it didn't set CORS if Java client was executed successfully ? Also, how do I verify if rule Policy "champ" is configured properly, if my generated SAS is correct and CORS properties are created or not**

Here is Java Client code:

```
public class CORS_and_SAS {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Define the connection-string with your values
    final String storageConnectionString ="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" + "AccountName=myacc;" + "AccountKey=B2q4AGp6YoRsTREXIkOv3e/Sxf46YzqzfnM9F8U+o7VA5Y3EiKc+CuritnvuyZxGXKNOQ5nJy2KfkniF970on1dQ==";
    try {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        // Create the blob client.
       CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

       // Get a reference to a container.
       // The container name must be lower case
       CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("mycon");

       // Create the container if it does not exist.
        //container.createIfNotExists();
       // Set CORS support
       //ServiceProperties blobServiceProperties = blobClient.GetServiceProperties();
       ServiceProperties propers = getCORS();
       blobClient.uploadServiceProperties(propers);
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
          GregorianCalendar calendar = 
             new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
          calendar.setTime(new Date());
          policy.setSharedAccessStartTime(calendar.getTime()); //Immediately applicable
          calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 3000); //Applicable time-span is 3000 hours
          policy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(calendar.getTime());           
          policy.setPermissions(EnumSet.of(SharedAccessBlobPermissions.READ, 
             SharedAccessBlobPermissions.WRITE, SharedAccessBlobPermissions.DELETE, 
             SharedAccessBlobPermissions.LIST));
          BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
          //Private container with no access for anonymous users
          containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.OFF);
          //Name the shared access policy: heath
          containerPermissions.getSharedAccessPolicies().put("champ", policy);
          container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);
          //Generate the policy SAS string for heath access
          String sas = container.generateSharedAccessSignature(
             new SharedAccessBlobPolicy(),"champ");           
          System.out.println("The stored access policy signature:");
          System.out.println(sas);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Output the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static ServiceProperties getCORS() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ServiceProperties propers = new ServiceProperties();
    CorsProperties corsprop = propers.getCors();

    CorsRule cr = new CorsRule();

    List<String> allowedHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
    allowedHeaders.add("x-ms-*");
    List<String> exposedHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
    exposedHeaders.add("x-ms-*");

    cr.setAllowedHeaders(allowedHeaders);
    cr.setExposedHeaders(exposedHeaders);
    EnumSet<CorsHttpMethods> allowedMethod = EnumSet.of(CorsHttpMethods.PUT,CorsHttpMethods.GET,CorsHttpMethods.POST,CorsHttpMethods.HEAD,CorsHttpMethods.DELETE);
    //EnumSet<CorsHttpMethods> allowedMethod1 = EnumSet.of(CorsHttpMethods.GET);
    cr.setAllowedMethods(allowedMethod);

    List<String> allowedOrigin = new ArrayList<String>();
    allowedOrigin.add("*");
    cr.setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigin);
    cr.setMaxAgeInSeconds(600);

    corsprop.getCorsRules().add(cr);

    //corsprop.getCorsRules().add(cr);
    propers.setCors(corsprop);
    return propers;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue, and checked carefully the Java Client code & erros in JS console. I found that the issue was caused by using blob container Shared Access Signature for the uploading file url.

Here is the Java code modified by yours.

```
private static final String accountName = "<account-name>";
private static final String accountKey = "<account-key>";
private static final String connectionStringTemplate = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=%s;AccountKey=%s";
private static final String containerName = "<block-blob-container-name>";
private static final String blobFileName = "<blob-file-name>";

public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException {
    String connectionString = String.format(connectionStringTemplate, accountName, accountKey);
    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();
    /*
     * Enable CORS
     */
    // CORS should be enabled once at service startup
    // Given a BlobClient, download the current Service Properties
    ServiceProperties blobServiceProperties = blobClient.downloadServiceProperties();
    // Enable and Configure CORS
    CorsProperties cors = new CorsProperties();
    CorsRule corsRule = new CorsRule();
    List<String> allowedHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
    allowedHeaders.add("*");
    EnumSet<CorsHttpMethods> allowedMethods = EnumSet.of(CorsHttpMethods.PUT, CorsHttpMethods.GET, CorsHttpMethods.HEAD, CorsHttpMethods.POST);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allowedMethods.toArray()));
    List<String> allowedOrigins = new ArrayList<String>();
    allowedOrigins.add("*");
    List<String> exposedHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
    exposedHeaders.add("*");
    int maxAgeInSeconds = 1800;
    corsRule.setAllowedHeaders(allowedHeaders);
    corsRule.setAllowedMethods(allowedMethods);
    corsRule.setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
    corsRule.setExposedHeaders(exposedHeaders);
    corsRule.setMaxAgeInSeconds(maxAgeInSeconds);
    cors.getCorsRules().add(corsRule);
    blobServiceProperties.setCors(cors);
    // Commit the CORS changes into the Service Properties
    blobClient.uploadServiceProperties(blobServiceProperties);
    /*
     * Generate the SAS for the uploading url
     */
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobFileName);
    SharedAccessBlobPolicy sharedAccessBlobPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    sharedAccessBlobPolicy.setSharedAccessStartTime(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    sharedAccessBlobPolicy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(calendar.getTime());
    sharedAccessBlobPolicy.setPermissions(EnumSet.of(SharedAccessBlobPermissions.WRITE));
    String sas = blockBlob.generateSharedAccessSignature(sharedAccessBlobPolicy, null);
    System.out.println(sas);
    String blobUploadSASURL = String.format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s?%s", accountName, containerName, blobFileName, sas);
    System.out.println(blobUploadSASURL);
}
```

Run the code and get the uploading blob SAS Url as the form `https://<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<blob-file-name>?sig=<SIG>&st=2015-12-01T11%3A51%3A20Z&se=2015-12-01T12%3A51%3A20Z&sv=2015-04-05&sp=r&sr=b`

Using PUT method with header `x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob` for the URL to upload a file successfully.

Further details and sample ajax code to do this is available, please refer to the blog from the Azure Storage team http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for reply Peter. User is going to select file dynamically so I don't have blobFileName beforehand. In this scenario, I should be able to generate SAS on "container" using following syntax right ? ...........  String sas = container.generateSharedAccessSignature(sharedAccessBlobPolicy, null);

Comment: @ios_mxe When user is going to select file dynamically, you can use JavaScript to get the file name and asynchronously generate SAS for blob file thru the backend Java code.